# VB.NET WithEvents keyword behavior - VB.NET compiler restriction?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr, vb.net-to-c#

I'm working on becoming as familiar with C# as I am with VB.NET (the language used at my workplace).  One of the best things about the learning process is that by learning about the other language you tend to learn more about your primary language--little questions like this pop up:

According to the sources I've found, and past experience, a field in VB.NET that is declared as *WithEvents* is capable of raising events.  I understand that C# doesn't have a direct equivalent--but my question is: fields *without* this keyword in VB.NET cannot raise events, is there a way to create this same behavior in C#?  Does the VB compiler simply block these objects from having their events handled (while actually allowing them to raise events as usual)?

I'm just curious; I don't have any particular application for the question...

Comment: +1 I'm trying the exact reversal, which means that I'm learning VBNET from C#. Thanks for your good question

Comment: @Will: have fun, VB.NET gets a bad rap for the 'VB' in it's name but is largely unfounded--VB.NET is an entirely different language from VB.  Just keep in mind that you should always set `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On`.  Those two lines will reign in a couple of the default compiler options.   If your experience is like mine you'll learn more about both languages.

Comment: yeah im same as Will and it was a help for me to understand what this WithEvents does :) thanks again!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Omitting WithEvents doesn't block members from raising events. It just stops you from using the 'handles' keyword on their events.

Here is a typical use of WithEvents:

```vb
Class C1
    Public WithEvents ev As New EventThrower()
    Public Sub catcher() Handles ev.event
        Debug.print("Event")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a class which doesn't use WithEvents and is approximately equivalent. It demonstrates why WithEvents is quite useful:

```vb
Class C2
    Private _ev As EventThrower
    Public Property ev() As EventThrower

        Get
            Return _ev
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As EventThrower)
            If _ev IsNot Nothing Then
                    removehandler _ev.event, addressof catcher
            End If
            _ev = value
            If _ev IsNot Nothing Then
                    addhandler _ev.event, addressof catcher
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        ev = New EventThrower()
    End Sub

    Public Sub catcher()
        Debug.print("Event")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I guess I'd never noticed that--probably because the only time I pay attention to it is when I get the error :-)