# VB.NET generates properties in the release build

Tags: vb.net, properties, build-process, field

I have a form and i drag and drop a control in VB.NET.

I have a line say,

```
private WithEvents radioButton RadioButton
```

Also, I have a handler like,

```
private void click(.....) Handles radioButton.Click
{
    ...
}
```

Now, When I build this is .NET 3.5 in release mode, and see the generated code in reflector tool, the code is something like,

```
Private Overridable Property radioButton As RadioButton
.
.
.
<AccessedThroughProperty("radioButton")> _
Private _radioButton As RadioButton
```

Can someone tell me what is going on here? 
And how do I avoid the generation of new properties and fields?

-datte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WithEvents/Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz(VS.90).aspx) construct is VB.NET syntax on top of the .NET Framework classes.
During the compilation process all language-specific keywords must be translated into the equivalent .NET Framework API calls, since that is what's available at runtime.

Related resources:

- [VB.NET WithEvents keyword behavior - VB.NET compiler restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840691/vb-net-withevents-keyword-behavior-vb-net-compiler-restriction)

Comment: And it's not specific to the Release build.