# Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a VB.net project that was converted from c# using Sharpdevelop.  When I open the project, I can run it fine.  Then I added a button to the form and all of a sudden 12 errors popped up saying:

> Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types

for lines that look like this:

```
Private Sub topListButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles topListButton.Click
```

This is the code that was converted from c#.  I am not sure why it ran originally but then bombed after I made a change to the project.

I tried removing the part of the lines with:

```
Handles topListButton.Click
```

but now the button clicks don't fire.  Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type`?

Comment: Add 'WithEvents' to your button declaration (you will probably find it in the designer code): `Private WithEvents topListButton As Button`

Comment: Thanks.  How do I do this?   Do I just add Private WithEvents topListButton As Button?

Comment: No. you look for the topListButton definition. it is already declared (as I wrote, probably in the designer code), and add the keyword WithEvents to it's declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.Net has some strange bugs (or features, depending on who's asking).
if you want to use the `Handles` keyword to attach event handlers, you must declare the object raising the event with the `WithEvents` keyword.
The strange thing about it is that the events will be raised with or without the `WithEvents` declaration, it's only purpose is to allow you to use the `Handles` keyword. you can still attach events to handlers using the [`Add handler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) statement.
You can see a code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840691/vb-net-withevents-keyword-behavior-vb-net-compiler-restriction).

Comment: `WithEvents` turns the field into a property that adds & removes handlers in its setter.  Without that, there would be no way for the compiler to hook up the event handlers.  There is nothing strange about it.

Comment: the strange thing actually is visual studio automatically lets you edit common events with event handlers but when the control is create through the manual design it doesn't actually create that "link" between the two like it usually does. i'm reading now about this matter because it never occurred to me in all the years with C# and it's happening only now that i'm beginning to work with VB

Answer (score 0):

Save the body of your `topListButton_Click` method (Ctrl-C), delete the whole method, re-create it by double-clicking the `topListButton` in the WinForms designer and insert the body again (Ctrl-V).