# EventArrived is Not working in ManagementEventWatcher vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The function `Watcher_EventArrived` is not working.

I have also added the reference but it is still not working.

[image]

```
Dim watcher As ManagementEventWatcher

Public Sub Main()
    Dim monitoredProcess = "Notepad.exe"

    Dim query As WqlEventQuery = New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process"" And TargetInstance.Name = """ & monitoredProcess & """")

    watcher = New ManagementEventWatcher()
    watcher.Query = query

    'This starts watching asynchronously, triggering EventArrived events every time a new event comes in.
    'You can do synchronous watching via the WaitForNextEvent() method
    watcher.Start()

End Sub

Public Sub Watcher_EventArrived(sender As Object, e As EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles watcher.EventArrived
    Console.WriteLine("Working")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `watcher` with [`WithEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents), otherwise you can't use the [`Handles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause)-clause.

```
Dim WithEvents watcher As ManagementEventWatcher
```

See also: [VB.NET WithEvents keyword behavior - VB.NET compiler restriction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840691/vb-net-withevents-keyword-behavior-vb-net-compiler-restriction)